# How do define binary type '01' data variable in nodejs code?

Tags: node.js, variables, types, binary

I need to get 01 binary value. Because my server need to send to module '00' or '01' binary values as binary. I just want to send '01' to module..

```js
const net = require('net');
const bi = require('binstring');


var server = net.createServer();
server.on("connection", function(socket){
  var remoteAddress = socket.remoteAddress +":"+ socket.remotePort;
  console.log("New client connection made %s ", remoteAddress);

  socket.on("data", function(d){
    console.log("Data from %s : %s" , remoteAddress,d);
    
    socket.write(01);
    console.log(d.toString());
  });

  socket.once("close", function(){
    console.log("Connection from %s deleted ", remoteAddress)
  });

  socket.on("error", function(err){
    console.log(err);
  })
});



server.listen(1245, function(){
  console.log("Port 1245 is open, server listening to %j", server.address());
})
```

Comment: as in just two bits?  What type of server are you building - how does it communicate?

Comment: It just only for confirmation. Module need to get 01 for getting the server accept their reply.

Comment: Can you share the code you already have?  For example if you are building an HTTP server you cannot send just two bits.  The answer largely depends on context

Comment: I added my code above